# Ember.js: How to test actions in controller

Tags: ember.js

I would like to unit test a controller, which fires an event when a property changes.

The controller looks something like this:

```
        App.MyController = Ember.Controller.extend({
           ...
            observeFilterFieldChanges: function() {
                console.log("observeFilterFieldChanges");
                this.setActiveSortField();
                this.send("queryChanged");
            }.observes("sorting.fields.@each.active"),
           ...
        });
```

And my test is the following:

```
    test('changing sort field via sort.fields will trigger query changed', function () {
        var queryChangedCalled = false;
        var tmpListController = App.MyController.create({
            actions: {
                queryChanged: function () {
                    console.log("querychanged called from controller");
                    queryChangedCalled = true;
                }
            }
        });

        // trigger the change
        tmpListController.set("sorting.fields.0.active", true);
        stop();

        // not sure if I need to wait for the run loop to finish
        Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', this, function () {
            start();
            ok(queryChangedCalled, "querChangedCalled should be true");
        });

    });
```

This doesn't work because the action queryChanged in the controller is never called. (But the observer does get called)

What is the best way for testing if the event was sent?

Update for clarity:
The above code works great in the App. The sent action is nicely consumed in the Route. All I want to is unit test to protect me against future changes :)

Comment: I am grateful you asking an ember testing question. However, I get mixed messages from your code, are you more interested in how to trigger an observer? Is your code simply not calling the send method from your test?  Both are interesting questions, but both would be better expressed with more succinct code examples and possibly a different title.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to test an action is to trigger it and assert whatever `this.setActiveSortField();` changes.

If the observer fails, the activeSortField fails asserting.
If the actions fails, it should throw an error.

```
moduleFor('controller:mycontroller', 'MyController Controller');

test('changing sort field via sort.fields will trigger query changed', function(assert) {
assert.expect(1);

// grab an instance of `MyController`
var ctrl = this.subject();

Ember.run(function() {

  ctrl.set('sorting.fields.0.active', true);
  assert.equal(ctrl.get('activeSortField'), 'bar');
});
```

See the updated testing Guide: http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/testing-controllers/